# Struts2 ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor

Tags: struts2

I'm having problem with closing the wait.jsp after the process is completed.  The configuration works fine with success result to another page.

However, when dealing with file downloads, the file is done downloading by the client, but the wait page is still there.  I would like to have it
closes automatically. I have searched but no luck. 
Can someone please help.

Comment: In general your wait.jsp should contain instruction to refresh page automatically. Like this: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=<s:url includeParams="all" />" />

Comment: If you don't want to show wait page then you should redirect to some other page and allow to download a file from it.

Comment: Mies, I have that line in my wait.jsp page but it still not working.

Comment: Show your action mapping from struts.xml.

Comment: <action name="DownloadFile" class="com.action.DownloadFileAction">
     <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
     <interceptor-ref name="params" />  
     <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
      <param name="delay">500</param>
         <param name="delaySleepInterval">50</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="wait">/WEB-INF/jsp/wait.jsp</result>

Comment: <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
        <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"    
        </param>
        <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
    </result>

Comment: @user1998820: Don't post code in the comments, edit your question instead. You cannot serve stream result and redirect simultaneously, so follow my advice in my first comment.

Comment: Configuration looks fine. Maybe the problem is that action immediately returns success result when download starts (at least this it how it looks in debug).

Comment: Thanks guys for helping.  ExecuteAndWait doesn't seem to feed on stream result.  So I had to use jquery ajax calls from action response on success then close it with jquery.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer. This will help future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 seems to handle with result success to another page but not result streaming.  So this is what I for the work around.

struts.xml

```
<action name="DownloadReport" class="com.actionet.fivs.action.DownloadReportAction">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
  <interceptor-ref name="params" />  
  <interceptor-ref name="execAndWait">
    <param name="delay">100</param>
    <param name="delaySleepInterval">50</param>
  </interceptor-ref>
  <result name="wait">/WEB-INF/jsp/wait.jsp</result>
  <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">application/octet-stream</param>
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"  </param>
    <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
  </result>
```

wait.jsp

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=<s:url includeParams="all" />"/>

//jquery to close the window when Action with success response
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax( {
  traditional: true,
  type: "POST",      
  url: "DownloadReport.action",
  data:"reportName="+reportName,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data, success) {
    if(data.indexOf("success") > -1){
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('','_self','');
        window.close();
        return false;
    }, 5000);   
   }
  }      
});
});
```